# $(a_n)$ tends to $0$ but $(\frac{1}{a_n})$ does not tend to infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

As part of a problem i am trying to solve i am required to give an example of a null sequence whose reciprocal does not tend to infinity any thoughts?
In formal terms give an example of a sequence $(a_n)$ such that

$$(a_n)\to0\ as\ n\to\infty $$ but $$(\frac{1}{a_n})\not\to\infty\ as\  n\to\infty$$

Comment: Consider $(-1)^n/n$.

Comment: Note FYI this is possible in $\mathbb R$, but not in $\mathbb C$. Your tag *does* specify real analysis, so -- okay.

Comment: Maybe $a_n = 0$ for all $n$.  Certainly $(a_n)$ converges to zero, but $1/a_n$ is undefined for all $n$.

Answer (score 1):

$-\frac1n$ works just fine. Or any other negative sequence that tends to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

A nice example would be:
$$a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$
which clearly converges to 0, since:
$0\leq\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n}\right|\leq\frac{1}{n}\overset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

But:
$b_n=\frac{1}{a_n}=(-1)^nn$
does not converge anywhere, since:
$$b_{2n}=n\to+\infty$$
but
$$b_{2n+1}=-n\to-\infty$$
So, by having two subsequences that do converge to different points, $b_n$ is **not convergent** (!).

Answer (score 0):

You need $$\frac{1}{a_n} \nrightarrow \infty$$ Fine. You can find a sequence in which $$\frac{1}{a_n} \to -\infty$$

That is, $$a_n \to 0^- , n \to \infty$$